# OpenGL on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, opengl

For some reason, OpenGL stopped working on my Ubuntu 12 system. Here is the error I get when running glxinfo:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  136 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
Serial number of failed request:  12
Current serial number in output stream:  12
```

I was searching Google for this error and all i found was some ATI related stuff. I dont have ATI card - I have laptop with intel video chip and no additional drivers.

What should I try to fix this error? What should I re-install?

Answer (score 2):

Had this error but under different circumstances. After replacing a motherboard with ATI video card to one with intel.

The solution for me was to uninstall ATI drivers, then reboot.

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx-amdcccle-updates fglrx-updates
```